# Pyparsing: dblQuotedString parsing differently in nestedExpr

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm working on a grammar to parse search queries (not evaluate them, just break them into component pieces). Right now I'm working with `nestedExpr`, just to grab the different 'levels' of each term, but I seem to have an issue if the first part of a term is in double quotes.

A simple version of the grammar:

```
QUOTED = QuotedString(quoteChar = '“', endQuoteChar = '”', unquoteResults = False).setParseAction(remove_curlies)
WWORD = Word(alphas8bit + printables.replace("(", "").replace(")", ""))
WORDS = Combine(OneOrMore(dblQuotedString | QUOTED | WWORD), joinString = ' ', adjacent = False)
TERM = OneOrMore(WORDS)
NESTED = OneOrMore(nestedExpr(content = TERM))

query = '(dog* OR boy girl w/3 ("girls n dolls" OR friends OR "best friend" OR (friends w/10 enemies)))'
```

Calling `NESTED.parseString(query)` returns:

```
[['dog* OR boy girl w/3', ['"girls n dolls"', 'OR friends OR "best friend" OR', ['friends w/10 enemies']]]]
```

The first `dblQuotedString` instance is separate from the rest of the term at the same nesting, which doesn't occur to the second `dblQuotedString` instance, and also doesn't occur if the quoted bit is a `QUOTED` instance (with curly quotes) rather than `dblQuotedString` with straight ones.

Is there something special about `dblQuotedString` that I'm missing?

NOTE: I know that `operatorPrecedence` can break up search terms like this, but I have some limits on what can be broken apart, so I'm testing if I can use `nestedExpr` to work within those limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nestedExpr` takes an optional keyword argument `ignoreExpr`, to take an expression that `nestedExpr` should use to ignore characters that would otherwise be interpreted as nesting openers or closers, and the default is pyparsing's `quotedString`, which is defined as `sglQuotedString | dblQuotedString`. This is to handle strings like:

```
(this has a tricky string "string with )" )
```

Since the default `ignoreExpr` is `quotedString`, the ')' in quotes is not misinterpreted as the closing parenthesis.

However, your `content` argument also matches on `dblQuotedString`. The leading quoted string is matched internally by `nestedExpr` by way of skipping over quoted strings that may contain "()"s, then your content is matched, which also matches quoted strings. You can suppress `nestedExpr`'s ignore expression using a `NoMatch`:

```
NESTED = OneOrMore(nestedExpr(content = TERM, ignoreExpr=NoMatch()))
```

which should now give you:

```
[['dog* OR boy girl w/3',
 ['"girls n dolls" OR friends OR "best friend" OR', ['friends w/10 enemies']]]]
```

You'll find more details and examples at https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing-module.html#nestedExpr